# Python3 Write to file beautifulsoup

Tags: python-3.x, beautifulsoup

I wish to write the beautifulsoup form  with this code:

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(con.content)
f = open('/*/*/Desktop/littletext.rtf','w')
f.write(str(soup))
f.close()
```

I get this error:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>       File "/*/*/Desktop/test123.py", line 10, in 
>       f.write(soup)
>       TypeError: must be str, not BeautifulSoup

Any ideas how to fix this? I tried to convert 'soup' to string but didn't work -- f.write(str(soup))

Comment: The code at the top of your question doesn't match the traceback. What does *"didn't work"* mean, exactly; what was the error message you actually got with `f.write(str(soup))`?

Comment: @jonrsharpe Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/*/*/Desktop/test123.py", line 10, in <module>
    f.write(str(soup))
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character '\u2026' in position 28521: ordinal not in range(128)

Comment: So you have read any of the numerous existing questions on dealing with `UnicodeEncodeError`s specifically or Unicode in Python generally, or e.g. https://docs.python.org/3/howto/unicode.html?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

found out my problem is that I had to use **'wb'** in

```
f = open('/*/*/Desktop/littletext.rtf','wb')
```

and

```
f.write(str(soup))
```

had to be

```
f.write(soup.encode('utf-8'))
```

Comment: Thanks for this straightforward solution!