# Python Script Website Scraping

Tags: python

I'm trying to scrape a website (http://forecast.weather.gov/MapClick.php?CityName=San+Francisco&state=CA&site=MTR&lat=37.7758&lon=-122.413#.WXlFZIQrJaR) to obtain the current observed temperature in Celsius and export that value to a text file.  Look for a tutorial in creating a python script to do this.  I've seen some for weatherunderground and using bs4; some for other sites but nothing that extracts the content to a file.  Point me to a website?

Comment: https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/

Comment: to save the webpage content to a file (write to a file) [Python3 Write to file beautifulsoup](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31451791/python3-write-to-file-beautifulsoup)

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

```
import urllib
import re

data = urllib.urlopen("http://forecast.weather.gov/MapClick.php?CityName=San+Francisco&state=CA&site=MTR&lat=37.7758&lon=-122.413#.WXot54qQxLz").read()


parsed = re.findall('<p class="myforecast-current-sm">(.*?)</p>', str(data))
temperature = re.findall("\d{1,}", parsed[0])
temp = temperature[0]
f = open('thefile.txt', 'a')
f.write(str(temp)+'\n')
f.close()
```

Contents of 'thefile.txt':

```
16
```

Answer (score 0):

Well first you have to scrap the content of the page with some module as bs4, [this page](https://www.dataquest.io/blog/web-scraping-tutorial-python/) actually explains how to do it on with the same web.

Then you have to process the data you got as you prefer to finally write it to a file.